# Make Javascript wait for an HTML element to exist

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a bot that sends virtual currency over to another user. I have the bot search through a database for users. Before searching, the inner html of a division has no elements at all. After searching, it is then filled with several user links.

Because it takes a short while for results to appear, I need Javascript to wait for at least one anchor tag to exist. How can I do this?

Comment: you can put your  java script function below the html control then first control loaded then your java script function will execute

Comment: Are you using asynchronous XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include an example of the structure, and the script that populates the structure.

Comment: Note to close voters: this is NOT an exact duplicate of the linked Q&A. The linked Q&A requires jQuery; this does not. There is a significant difference between the two.

Answer (score 1):

There are many, many better ways to do this, all of which stem from actually checking when the AJAX data populates the element itself, but the following will work:

```
var t = setInterval(function () {
  if ($("element").children().length > 0) {
    clearInterval(t);
    // do stuff
  }
}, 50);
```

Comment: Create a new jQuery object, query the DOM, and call a function to return an array of children just to check the length of the array every 50 milliseconds then throw it all away if the length is 0 every time until your script finds it? That seems quite excessive.

Comment: Also, this question does not have a jQuery tag, [`Unless a tag for a framework or library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected for questions with the javascript tag.`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info)

Answer (score 0):

Using setTimeout() to delay the code a few seconds is risky, since on older browser/machines it may take longer than expected.

Use promise() instead, You can find documentation https://api.jquery.com/promise/ .

Comment: This question does not have a jQuery tag, [`Unless a tag for a framework or library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected for questions with the javascript tag.`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info)

Comment: Okay, then use javascript promises.

Answer (score 0):

Using onload event, You can use onload with tag a.
EX: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_img_onload

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is an AJAX call.

You could use AJAX `callback` to check if you got any results from the server.

Something like this:

```
var tags_available = false;
$.ajax({
   ... the ajax stuff;
}).done(function(data){ // The callback
  if(data || $('#tags_element').lenght != 0){
    tags_available = true;
  }else{
    tags_available = false;
  }
})
```

Then:

```
if(tags_available){
  console.log("Tags available")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you correctly you need to check if dom element have been updated/populated with new elements. There are a few ways you can achieve that:

1.) Using window.setTimeout function

```js
function checkForChanges() {
  var observeThis = document.getElementById('observethis');
  if (observeThis.hasChildNodes()) {
    alert('yes');
    return;
    /*this is gonna execute only once */
  }
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    checkForChanges();
  }, 25);
}

checkForChanges();

/* this part is only relevant for demonstration. 
It shows what happens when dom element gets new child */
(function() {
  var observeThis = document.getElementById('observethis');
  var button = document.getElementById('button-append');
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var anchorElement = document.createElement('a');
    anchorElement.href = "http://example.com";
    anchorElement.target = "_blank";
    anchorElement.innerHTML = "Link";
    observeThis.appendChild(anchorElement);
  }, false);
})();
```

```html
<div id="observethis"></div>
<button id="button-append">append anchor</button>
```

2.) MutationObserver class

this is modern approach (I would also say recommended one).

```js
function checkForChanges() {
  var observeThis = document.getElementById('observethis');
  // create an observer instance
  var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
      if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
        alert("insert your own code");
      }
    });
  });
  var config = {
    attributes: true,
    childList: true,
    characterData: true
  };
  observer.observe(observeThis, config);
  //observer.disconnect(); 
  //use observer.disconnect to end observations
}

checkForChanges();

/* this part is only relevant for demonstration. 
It shows what happens when dom element gets new child */
(function() {
  var observeThis = document.getElementById('observethis');
  var button = document.getElementById('button-append');
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var anchorElement = document.createElement('a');
    anchorElement.href = "http://example.com";
    anchorElement.target = "_blank";
    anchorElement.innerHTML = "Link";
    observeThis.appendChild(anchorElement);
  }, false);
})();
```

```html
<div id="observethis"></div>
<button id="button-append">Append Child</button>
```

Read more about MutationObserver [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

3.) If you are just waiting to get a response from ajax callback and don't actually need to observe changes in dom then just use XMLHttpRequest. Or even better. Use new javascript [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) API (you are gonna need [polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch) to ensure it works in most browsers)